# Flask can't find directory.. returns a 404?

Tags: python, flash, flask, client, directory

## **Directory Structure:**

- static

  - game

    - something1.swf
    - something2.swf
    - something3.swf
- templates

  - something.html
- main.py

---

I have a small web game application that interacts with Flash .SWF files to show the images and everything back to the website.

If I call **./static/game/something1.swf**, it loads. It loads any other file that is being called specifically, however my application needs to call the whole directory in general for whatever reason.

If I call **./static/game/** or **./static/game**, for some reason, Flask returns a 404 error. It's like the directory does not exist at all to Flask. My hypothesis is that Flask sees **game** as a file, when it isn't.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Flask doesn't serve directories, only files. Without a file name Flask doesn't know what to serve and returns a file not found.

Comment: @JasonDecastro Show us the code, which you think makes Flask to serve your swf file. Anyway, in production, this kind of file would be served by some web server in front of your app (like nginx) to offload your Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Flask doesn't produce directory views; that's something generic file-serving HTTP servers like Apache and nginx *can* do (if so configured) but it is not functionality that Flask offers out of the box. You'd have to code this yourself.